# Difference between tooling and tool?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, differences

I am doing research for my faulty, while that, I have stumbled upon the word "tooling" in a sentence, it seems to be similar to "tool".

---

Here is the sentence:

> Rapid tooling for sand casting using laminated object manufacturing process.

---

When to use each one in its context?

Comment: Your example seems to be from https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/13552549910278964/full/html. Could you please give the source and some context in future? Your example is a title of a paper and thus not subject to the usual grammatical conventions.  When you looked at "tooling" in the dictionary, what did you find?

Comment: That is true, it is the title of the paper, I have looked up "tooling", but, unfortunately, there is no complete and precise definition with examples.

Comment: "Tooling" is often used to mean a collection of tools, or a technology for accomplishing a task.  Originally this referred to tools for physically shaping something, but it has acquired a metaphorical meaning and the word is often used when describing facilities for, eg, computer programming.

Comment: It depends on if you are talking about an overall process (*tooling*) or a particular thing (*tool*).

Comment: That is not a sentence, by the way. It's a noun phrase that includes a prepositional phrase, and all of the meaningful words are multiply ambiguous because they're out of context. Inside the context, it probably makes sense; but outside, it just isn't clear what _tooling_ means here. It could mean an industrial process -- tooling up for production. It could mean acquiring tools, or distributing them, or training in use of them. It could mean the type and style of tool(s) used in sand casting (whatever that is, and whatever they are). It could mean literally hundreds of other things.